# What are good Twitter hashtags we should use when sharing questions from our Freelancing SE site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As someone who shares a lot of content on Twitter, I recently discovered that anything that I tag with #JavaScript gets automatically retweeted to over 4200+ more followers, thanks to [js_digest](https://twitter.com/js_digest). [A recent question, which involved JavaScript](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/how-to-know-when-you-are-a-competent-enough-programmer-to-charge-clients), gave me an opportunity to share this post with more people by adding the #JavaScript hashtag.

But our site isn't about programming; it's about freelancing. Some freelancing questions may loosely relate to other fields, such as JavaScript, but that's not where my expertise is.

So to people in the Freelancing SE community who dabble in things outside of programming, this includes artists, writers, sales consultants ([yes, I guess that's a thing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/how-to-find-and-evaluate-a-freelance-commission-based-sales-person-for-digital-a)), or any other professionals contributing to our site, what hashtags should we use when sharing questions that will maximize the chances of those posts being retweeted to more followers?

Is there a hashtag for freelancing that will result in retweets?  How can we leverage Twitter and other social media more effectively in sharing our valuable content?

Comment: #firstworldproblems? Jk

Comment: lol @CanadianLuke.

Comment: In case you can't tell, I don't use Twitter

Answer (score 2):

While the javascript hashtag does get automated retweets, the auto-retweeting of hashtags isn't something that's hugely common in my (rather limited) understanding of the twitterverse. Especially since it isn't possible to follow hastags directly, the use of a twitter account where questions are tweeted automatically is probably the best solution.  This allows for people to follow the account and see the questions directly.

Additionally, each freelancing question may itself be difficult to categorise due to the wide number of fields in which it is possible to freelance, as you've mentioned.

I did spend some time looking at the freelance culture on twitter and #selfemployed seemed to be doing well. Perhaps keeping an eye on #selfemployed and tweeting the people who post questions/relevant issues on twitter  with details about the site can help gain a bit more attention.

I definitely think that it's a good idea to start on reddit. This is a great place to get a lot of freelancers in one spot and tell them about us. It may be a great selling point we have the twitter account they can follow (you don't have to check the site every day then, most people are on twitter in any case). Then retweets and follows will happen naturally.